# What is the differences between declaring a variable inside and outside the class?

Tags: kotlin

Here is the example:

Declare inside the class

```
class User {
    private val greeting = "Hello, World!"
}
```

Declare outside the class

```
private val greeting = "Hello, World!"
```

Answer (score 4):

The property declared inside the `class` is part of that class.  This means that **each instance of the class has its own version of the property**, separate from the others.  (Conversely, if you never create any instances of the class, there are *no* versions of that property anywhere.)

Because it's `private`, **you can access it only from with the class**; it's not visible to any other code.

In this case, because it's a `val` with a constant initialiser, each instance will get a reference to the same string, so you might think it's a bit pointless.  But it can still be a good way to restrict access to the property, and make its connection to the class obvious to anyone reading it.

---

The property declared outside the class is **a top-level property**.  This belongs to the package, and is the nearest thing Kotlin has to a global.  **There is exactly one** of these.  (So each instance of `User` would refer to the *same* `greeting` — though again, because it's a `val` with a constant initialiser, that doesn't make any practical difference in this case.)

**You can access it from anywhere in that file**, but because it's `private` it's not visible to code in any other file.

Answer (score 1):

This boils down to the fact that Kotlin allows you to create files that do **not** contain classes, but only "top level" declarations. See their [userguide](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coding-conventions.html#source-file-names).

Or, in other words:

> A top level declaration is a function or property which is defined outside any class, object, interface or other structure.

(from [here](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/singleton-top-level-declaration-module/7711))

Thus: there is a fundamental difference. Your first example is a field that only exists in the scope of that class. The other one is a well, module wide private variable.